# Help identifying plant

Tags: species-identification

I saw this plant during the summer in Yorkshire, in the north of England. It was found near in a lowland area not too far from a river, but not in a boggy / marshy place. I’ve also seen them ok roadside verges as well.

I think it’s possibly related to a Lily, but I’m not sure at all about that.

Does anyone know what species this might be?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This plant is a bellflower. Either a Campanula Takesimana or a Campanula Alliariifolia

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 